# Conditional statement not triggered

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I wrote a piece of code that creates a random string based on an input. The user decides its length and whether it should contain numbers and special characters. I added a fail-safe routine because the end result is random:

```
def create
  i = @number
  while i != 0
    # testing the script I have noticed that the if statement is (always) ignored.
    if i == 2 && (@word_bank.include?(@special_chars) && @rand_ary.include?(@special_chars) == false)
      @rand_ary << @special_chars[rand(0..@special_chars.size - 1)]
    end
    letter = rand(0..word_bank.size - 1)
    #puts "#{i}, #{word_bank[letter]}"
    @rand_ary << word_bank[letter]
    word_bank.delete_at(letter)
    i -= 1
  end
  @rand_string = @rand_ary.join()
  puts @rand_string
  @rand_string
end
```

If the user elects to include a special character, a counter runs from n - 0. When i = 2, and no character from a special character array is included, a random special character is manually included.

But this `if`-statement is never triggered. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Probably because condition `i == 2 && (@word_bank.include?(@special_chars) && @rand_ary.include?(@special_chars) == false)` always returns `false` ;)

Comment: Fabio doesn't `@word_bank.include?(@special_chars)`  translate to `@word_bank.include?(@special_chars) == true` ?   I've tried both versions to no avail (elected to go with the first version b/c it's more ruby-esque...  am I wrong?

Comment: It's rarely necessary in Ruby to say `x == false`, that only matters when you're differentiating between `nil` and `false`. Instead say `!x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your variables have the kind of values I think they do, it's because `include` isn't the right method to use here.

If `@word_bank` and `@rand_ary` are arrays, `include` will check if any single element is equal to `@special_chars`. If `@special_chars` is itself an array, then it'll only return true if one of the elements in `@word_bank`/`@rand_ary` is an array.

```
['a', 'b', 'c', '!'].include?('!') # => true
['a', 'b', 'c', '!'].include?(['!']) # => false
['a', 'b', 'c', ['!']].include?(['!']) # => true
```

I think you're actually interested in whether there's any overlap between them. In that case, you can use the intersection (`&`) operator and check whether it's empty.

```
['a', 'b', 'c', '!'] & ['!'] # => ['!']
['a', 'b', 'c'] & ['!'] # => []
```

Comment: Based on  `@rand_ary << @special_chars[rand(0..@special_chars.size - 1)]` special_chars is an array.  I am so missing strong type features ;)

Comment: @Max `@word_bank` + `@rand_ary` ARE both arrays.  To ask how do u incorporate `&` into an `if statement` succinctly? having difficulty on this with google & ruby-doc

Comment: You can also `['a', 'b', 'c', '!'].grep('!')` which can also use regular expressions as well to be more flexible.

Comment: I just tried `if i == 2 && (@word_bank & @special_chars && @password_ary & @special_chars == false)` and the test failed on the first try...

Comment: @foo It'd be something like `if !(@word_bank & @special_chars).empty?` for the first condition.

Comment: @Max that seems to have done the trick.  To clarify:  1. `.include?` isn't built for array searches? and 2.( for educational purposes) are there any resource advantages between `grep()` or `.empty?`

Comment: @foo For 1., it can search for arrays, but it compares the argument to each element of the first array, one at a time. So, with `x.include?(y)`, it'll go through each element of `x` to see if that element is equal to `y`. If `y` is an array, it'll only return true if one of the elements of `x` is itself an array (so, a nested array).

Comment: @foo 2. I think that `grep` is actually going to run into the same issue as `include?` here, because if you pass an array to `grep`, it'll look to see whether each element in the first array is equal to the array, not whether there's overlap between the two arrays. And at any rate, the result of `grep` is an array, so you still have to call `empty?` on that. I don't know in particular about performance impacts of each method.